# Azure Purview fails to classify Azure Data Explorer databases

Tags: azure, azure-purview

I followed the [documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSS5S.png) for scanning ADX assets with Azure Purview, created an active connection with all the required permissions, and triggered a scan. The scan was successful, but no assets (tables, columns, etc) were identified. I tried multiple scans with the default and custom scanning rule sets, but nothing.

With the command: ***".show commands"*** I was able to see that Purview successfully submitted the command ***".show database details | project TotalSize, RetentionPolicy, CachingPolicy"*** to ADX

[image]

but still no assets where created in the data catalog.

[image]

I have no idea what to do next to try and find the problem.

Comment: For Purview issues please redirect your questions to purviewchamps@microsoft.com as a first pass in that case.